# is there a way to selfupdate maven without re-downloading the newer version

Tags: maven

Is there a way to update the maven distribution without re-downloading the newer version and fixing the new path in the environment path?

something like: `mvn selfupdate` (the macport style)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The download? The enviroment?

Comment: neither, I just want to easily upgrade it ;)

Comment: See the given answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but the Maven install is only a very thin bootstrap anyway.....

Maven downloads most of it's functionality as plugins. This normally happens when you run your first build and stores them in a local repository under:

```
$HOME/.m2/repository
```

So the good news is that when you install the new version of Maven, it will re-use the plugins already downloaded (unless newer ones are required).

Finally if you have concerns about performance it's an excellent idea to install a Maven repository manager. Software like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) can proxy and cache external repositories like Maven Central and will significantly improve your build performance (and enable off-line  builds). [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) is very lightweight, I run it on my laptop.